# How to fix Debug assertion failed while loading dll dialog using AfxGetResourceHandle()?

Tags: debugging, dll, mfc, dialog, assertion

I am working on a project on VC++ using MFC. I have a client and I'm calling `Dll1` from it which works fine. I have a `DLL2` whose dialog I want to call through `Dll1` but I am facing Debug Assertion Failure msg. I even tried to call it through my client but same problem persists.

Dll1.h has:

```
extern  "C"  __declspec(dllexport) BOOL DishDesign( Dish * ptr_dish );
```

DLL2 dllmain has:

```
extern"C"_declspec(dllexport) BOOL DishDesign( Dish * ptr_dish )
{
    HINSTANCE hInstOld = AfxGetResourceHandle();
    AfxSetResourceHandle(DishdllDLL.hModule);
    DISHDLG Dlg;
    Dlg.ptr_dish_in=ptr_dish;
    BOOL JobDone = FALSE;

    if(IDOK == Dlg.DoModal())
    {
        JobDone = TRUE;
    }
    else 
    {
    }

    AfxSetResourceHandle(hInstOld); 
    return JobDone;
}
```

I get the following error at `HINSTANCE hInstOld = AfxGetResourceHandle();`

> Debug Assertion Failed. and it breaks to  { ASSERT(afxCurrentResourceHandle != NULL);

I have checked all the settings, passing of source address, everything is proper. 
Please guide how to resolve this.

Comment: [TN058: MFC Module State Implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn058-mfc-module-state-implementation).